# How to change the datatype of a field of a loaded dataset from Text to Date

Tags: elk

I am new to ELK stack and I am working with a small project in which I am trying to visualize fake reviews from a reviews dataset. I loaded the dataset which consists of fields like Price of the product, Review Score and Date of review etc. As all of them are in text format I am facing some difficulties while forming a graph out of them. I need some help to convert the Date of review from text to Date format.

Values in the field are in the format

```
"21-02-2009"
"22-02-2009"
..
```

These are all in string format. I wanted to convert them to Date format

I tried executing the following query

```
PUT softwarerevs/_mapping?include_type_name=true
{
  "properties": {
    "Time": {
      "format": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
      "type" : "date"
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;"
      }
    ],
    "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
    "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use logstash to reindex the data with some filters. For filtering the date field you can use the date filter plugin.

Below is the format

```
    date {
       match => [ sourcefield , <date-format> ]
       target => destinationfield
    }
```

you can find the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target)

Sample conf file

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "host
        index => "index"
        query => '{ "query": { "match_all": {} } }'
        scroll => "20m"
        docinfo => true
    }
}
filter {
    date {
           match => [ sourcefield , <date-format> ]
           target => destinationfield
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "host"
        index => "new-index"
}
```